# User Signup using passport+express+mysql+sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to build a user signup api using Passport, MySql, NodeJS and Sequelize. The only problem that i face is that when a user has signed up once and he tries to sign up again with the same email user is thrown a 401 Unauthorized Error instead of the user object. When i tried to debug the same the response that i was getting from the server was this 
[object SequelizeInstance:users]. The files have been mentioned below. Thanks a tonnn in advance!!!.

Passport.js file:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Model = require('../models/models.js');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {
    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            connection.query("select * from users where id = " + id, function(err, rows) {
                    done(err, rows[0]);
            });
    });


    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
                    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
                    usernameField: 'email',
                    passwordField: 'password',
                    passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            function(req, email, password, done) {
                    Model.User.findOne({
                            where: {
                                    email: email
                            }
                    }).then(function(user) {
                            if (user == null) {
                                    Model.User.create({
                                            email: email,
                                            password: password
                                    }).then(function(user) {
                                            return done(null, user);
                                    }).catch(function(err) {
                                            return done(null, err);
                                    });
                            } else {
                                    return done(null, false);
                            }
                    })

            }));
```

};

The Signup api:

```
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup'), function(req, res) {
                // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
                // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
                console.log(req.user);
                if(req.user){
                    res.send({
                        success: true,
                        response: 'signup successful'
                    });
                } else {
                    res.send({
                        success: false,
                        response: 'Email already in use'
                    });
                }
        });
```

The User model is:

```
//models/users.js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')

var attributes = {
                id: {
                        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                        primaryKey: true,
                        autoIncrement: true
                },
                name: {
                        type: Sequelize.STRING
                },
                email: {
                        type: Sequelize.STRING
                },
                password: {
                        type: Sequelize.STRING
                },
                created_by: {
                        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                }
}

var options = {
                // Add the timestamps attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
                timestamps: true,

                // don't delete database entries but set the newly added attribute deletedAt
                // to the current date (when deletion was done). paranoid will only work if
                // timestamps are enabled
                paranoid: true,

                // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
                // so updatedAt will be updated_at
                underscored: true,

                // disable the modification of table names; By default, sequelize will automatically
                // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
                // if you don't want that, set the following
                freezeTableName: true,

                // define the table's name
                tableName: 'users'
}

module.exports.attributes = attributes
module.exports.options = options
```

The automated table creation model script is:

```
// models/models.js
var UserMeta = require('./users.js'),
        connection = require('./index.js')

var User = connection.define('users', UserMeta.attributes, UserMeta.options)
        // force: true will drop the table if it already exists
User.sync({
        force: true,
        match: /_servernew$/
}).then(function() {
        // Table created
        return User.create();
});
// you can define relationships here
module.exports.User = User;
```

Comment: Im slightly confused with what you want to achieve... when a user wants to sign up with the same credentials then the program acts correctly - as the email address is already in use with a specified user so cant be used for a sign up again?

Comment: When the user has already signed up once but he tries to sign up again with the same email then the response is 401 unauthorized and the user object is logged in console as [object SequelizeInstance:users] and the passport does not return a correct response just using this done(null, false) to the api route in routes/index.js where the signup api has been written.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're using raw queries you **need** to use [placeholder values](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/). Using string concatenation for values without escaping leads to serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman Thank you i will remove it for sure and replace it with the sequelize model methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i came up with the solution. The following code needs to be changed.

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
                passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
                        if(user){
                                req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                                        if (err) { 
                                                return next(err); 
                                        } else {
                                                res.send({
                                                        success: true,
                                                        response: 'signup successful'
                                                });
                                        }
                                });
                        }

                        if(!user){
                                res.send({
                                        success: false,
                                        response: 'Authentication Failed'
                                });
                        }

                        if(err){
                                res.send({
                                        success: false,
                                        response: 'Authentication failed'
                                })
                        }
                })(req, res, next);
        });
```

and the passport.js code should be like this.

```
 // =========================================================================
        // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
        // =========================================================================
        // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
        // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

        passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
                        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
                        usernameField: 'email',
                        passwordField: 'password',
                        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
                },
                function(req, email, password, done) {

                        Model.User.findOne({
                                where: {
                                        email: email
                                }
                        }).then(function(user, err) {
                                console.log('I entered'+user);
                                console.log('I entered'+err);
                                if(err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                        return done(null, false);
                                }

                                if(user == null) {
                                                Model.User.create({
                                                        email: email,
                                                        password: password
                                                }).then(function(user) {
                                                        return done(null, user);
                                                }).catch(function(err) {
                                                        return done(null, err);
                                                });
                                }

                                if(user){
                                        return done(null, false);
                                }

                        })

                }));
```

It will work just like a charm :D.

Comment: Hi need a help from you regarding the user signup can you help me?

Comment: @kannan sure what is it?

Comment: I want to perform a signup and login operation with passport bro i had done it in Mongoose but this sequelize is too confusing for me the fields will be username and password. Can you suggest me where/how to start ?

Comment: @kannan Sure no problem first you have to check which type of login you want to go ahead with that is token based or session based and have you tried implementing the solution that I have written above?

Comment: I want to go with token based bro json web token. No bro actually am struck up with sequelize association issues bro that is why i even replied to this thread lately. Is it yours token based?

Comment: @kannan It is not a token based one. Can you tell me where are you stuck?

Comment: Am struck with the basics itself bro if you are free tonight we can discuss further went for a vacation bro so couldn't reply earlier